# Синоним к слову "понты"

Tags: сленг

Какой синоним у слова "понты"?
Этот вопрос мне попался на просторах интернета и всерьез заинтересовал: а действительно, какой синоним или синонимическое словосочетание тут можно подобрать? Гонор, спесь, гордыня? Но это все не совсем то.
А еще интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова и к чему его правильнее отнести: к жаргону или к сленгу?
Кстати, вот, я считаю, что эта картинка очень удачно отображает суть самого понятия:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синонимами к слову "понты" будут *хлестаковщина*, *чванство*.

Так как у разных авторов подходы к границе между терминами "жаргон" и "сленг" разнятся, то без собственного определения терминологии (что выходит за рамки вопроса) разграничить не удасться.

Этимология "понта" скорей всего от карточного термина "понтер", человек играющий против банкомета.

Answer (score 2):

> > какой синоним или синонимическое словосочетание тут можно подобрать? Гонор, спесь, гордыня? Но это все не совсем то.

Конечно, не совсем то. Синонимы – это слова, близкие по значению и употреблению. БЛИЗКИЕ, а не одинаковые. Полных синонимов в языке вообще не существует, язык их не терпит. Так что эти гонор, спесь, гордыня – вполне себе синонимы для понтов.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое выражение: "Хороший понт, дороже денег!" Понты - это блеф. Пример:" - Как ты этих фраеров на бабки развёл? - А я на понт их взял, что у меня ствол(пистолет) в кармане." Это чисто жаргонное слово, происходящее, по моему личному мнению, от слова "понятия", так же жаргонного. "Понятия" - это понимание воровского закона; "жить по-понятиям", значит жить  в соответствии с тюремными устоями. Понтоваться - значит, делать вид, создавать иллюзию того,
что живёшь по-понятиям. Есть ещё несколько значений у этого слова. 1)Выгода, результат("Какой мне с этого понт будет?" "Это беспонтовая идея!" "Беспонтовый (бессмысленный) разговор"...). 2)Украшение("Понтов(золотых цепей, перстней...) навешал на себя!" "Понтовое(красивое) у тебя платье!") По-сути украшение - это тот же блеф, так как, украшая себя, человек стремится восполнить или скрыть её природный недостаток, отсюда и подобная семантика.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря ненормативной лексики:

ПОНТ (жарг).

1) Нарочитое хвастовство, показушность, апломб, гонор, словосочетания: это так, для понта;  с понтом дамочка (вертихвостка).

2)Вымысел, уловка, хитрость, словосочетания: понт бить (возмущаться, изображая честного человека) , понт наводить (создавать видимость благополучия), без понта (всерьез),брать на понт, понты гнать (добиваться обманным путем, запугиванием), с понтом (будто бы).

О происхождении слова "понт"

"Понтером называли человека, играющего против банка (в азартных играх) , понтировать — значит играть как понтёр. Однако возможно, отмечает автор Словаря русского арго Владимир Елистратов, современный понт пришел из уголовного жаргона.Ну а теперь надо разобраться, откуда понт появился в воровском жаргоне".

ПОНТЁР - 18 век, от ponter - делать ставку.

ПОНТИФИК - 20 век, от pontifex - жрец.

ПОНТОН - 19 век, от фр. ponton, из лат. pons - мост

"Слово это имеет латинские корни. Pons - значит мост. Родственно ему и слово понтифик. Как уточняет энциклопедия Брокгауза и Эфрона, жрецы, носившие это имя, первоначально должны были наблюдать за ремонтом и постройкой свайного моста в Риме. В религиозном отношении он имел огромное значение. То есть первоначально понт действительно означал высокую миссию, однако при переходе в жаргон подлинное превосходство превратилось в ложное". http://otvet.mail.ru/question/5268171

ПОНТИФИК - это "наводящий мосты". Мост у разных народов выступал в качестве метафоры связующего звена между непостижимым и доступным для постижения. У римлян понтификом назывался верховный жрец. Кроме того, река почиталась как священное божество, и возведение моста было актом своеобразного насилия над хозяином водной стихии.  Поэтому понтифики наблюдали за строительством, причем допускалось использование только природных материалов (камня, дерева, но не железа).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то не "понты" а "пАнты" -- рога оленя, красивые такие штуки, но абсолютно бесполезные, чисто создание видимости... и ни каких синонимов не надо.

Представляете себе оленя с рогами... гордый такой, боднуть пытается... вот это и называется "пантоваться".

И рога у оленя каждый год отваливаются, возможно это и есть "панты кидать".